# Como cancelar um XMLHttpRequest usando um botão?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Estou criando um script para upload de arquivos que será divido em chunks de acordo com o tamanho do arquivo, criando assim diversas requisições com partes diferentes do arquivo, porém eu gostaria de colocar a opção em que o usuário possa cancelar um upload.

Essa é a função que faz o upload do arquivo:

```
function uploadFile(e, uploadID){
    var chunks = e.chunks;
    var location = e.location;
    var cnt = 0;
    var end = chunks.length;

    var temp = 
              function callback(cnt){
                    var e = chunks[cnt];
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("PUT", location, true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', e.range);
                    xhr.send(e.data);
                    xhr.onloadend = 
                                function() {
                                            var status = xhr.status;

                                            cnt += 1;

                                            if (status == 308) {
                                                callback(cnt);
                                            } else if (status == 200) {
                                                console.log("Upload feito");
                                            } else {
                                                console.log("Erro: " + xhr.response);
                                            }
                                        };
    }(cnt);
}
```

Sei que é possível fazer um abort() no objeto para cancelar a requisição, porém como eu poder fazer para cancelar só quando o usuário clicar em um botão? Devo salvar o objeto XMLHttpRequest() em alguma parte para chamar depois ou existe algum tipo de identificador que eu posso usar para cancelar a requisição?

Por exemplo, eu poderia definir uma variável global e salvar o objeto da requisição nela, porém se eu tiver mais de um arquivo sendo upado, como faço para manter o controle de qual requisição deve ser cancelada? Uma vez que a cada novo upload a variável vai ser atualizada com um novo objeto.

Comment: @dvd Eu sei que é possível usar o abort(), meu problema é como fazer para chamá-lo através de um botão? E depois se eu tiver vários arquivos em upload a variável que contem o objeto mudará cada vez que um novo arquivo for enviado. Eu quero saber como reconhecer qual upload deve ser cancelado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa o método `abort`:  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

```
// a variável deve ser global ou ser passada por parâmetro para a function que irá abortar
var xhrList = [];
function uploadFile(e, uploadID){ 
    // aqui deve haver um id que identifique o arquivo (chamei abaixo de "x")
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrList.push({ id: x, obj: xhr});
}

function abortar(id) {
  var xhr = xhrList.find(x => x.id === id).obj;
  xhr.abort();
}
```

**EDIT**: editado após a edição da pergunta explicando o cenário para abortar uma requisição em específico.

Basta executar `abortar()` no click do botão.
Antes de executar o `abort` verificar o status da requisição em `xhr.status` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status

Comment: quem votou negativo pode explicar o que há de inútil ou errado na resposta por gentileza?

Comment: Funcionária bem se fosse para fazer o upload de 1 arquivo por vez, se eu tiver mais de 1 arquivo, a cada novo arquivo a var xhr vai ser atualizada com um novo objeto

Comment: neste caso, quer cancelar todos ou apenas um upload em particular?

Comment: Um em particular, aquele que o usuário escolher, por isso me serviria saber se existe um ID para as requisições ou algo do genero

Comment: veja a edição que fiz na pergunta. `XMLHttpRequest` não tem um identificador, mas você pode atribuir um a uma lista ao armazenar a requisição, e excluir essa em particular

Comment: Ué também não entendi o -1, a resposta parece completamente válida

Comment: Interessante, em vez de salvar em uma variável global, tenho outras opções de onde salvar? Visto que são funções que serão chamadas de scripts diferentes, não quero correr o risco de sofrer com escopos de variáveis

Comment: A variável nesse exemplo ainda acaba sendo global. Se precisar acessar de scripts diferentes, todos os scripts precisariam acessar a variável. Sobre salvar é possível, mas isso funciona bem com dados números, textos, ou mesmo classes mais simples. Nesse caso como é um objeto de `XMLHttpRequest` não sei como funcionaria a serialização, precisaria testar. Nesse caso o `localStorage` poderia ser uma opção, mas eu ainda tentaria com a variável global.